# Convert to Datetime MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

How to convert given date format to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

I tried this one below but not achieved. Can anyone help me?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Comment: What is the ***120 value***?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Supported by SQL Server 2005 and later versions**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
       + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

* See Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) to understand what the `101` and `108` style codes above mean.

**Supported by SQL Server 2012 and later versions**

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

**Result**

Both of the above methods will return:

```
10/16/2013 17:00:20
```

Comment: @Kiquenet it is the third parameter `Style` for [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: Is there a way to go reverse? I want to convert Varchar to Date from this string '08/15/18, 12:10:40 PM'. TIA

Comment: I highly recommend sticking with the SQL Server 2005 solution. The FORMAT solution looks convenient but it is many times slower when you have more than a few records.

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
select convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(), 103) + 
       ' '+
       right(convert(varchar(32),GETDATE(),108),8) AS Date_Time
```

It will Produce:

> Date_Time 30/03/2015 11:51:40

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @month as char(2)
Declare @date as char(2)
Declare @year as char(4)
declare @time as char(8)
declare @customdate as varchar(20)

set @month = MONTH(GetDate());
set @date = Day(GetDate());
set @year = year(GetDate());

set @customdate= @month+'/'+@date+'/'+@year+' '+ CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(),108);
print(@customdate)
```