# sqlserver format date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am not familar with sql server why i have the following error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
...
values (1, 'P' + char(10) + 'd' + char(10) + 'inst',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),'18-01-2016 11:29:27',113))
```

the code for 13  is =   `dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm (24h)` is it possible wrong code ?

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409521/convert-to-datetime-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-in-sql-server) also didnt work

```
values (1, 'P' + char(10) + 'd' + char(10) + 'inst',
 format('18-01-2016 11:29:27','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: I get no errors trying to convert the date to varchar... Can you provide a more specific example of the error?

Comment: @bastos.sergio changing to datetime seems worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the **target** type of `CONVERT` should be `DATETIME`...

The format code you've tried expects the month as word (`mon` != `mm`)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'18 jan 2016 11:29:27',113);
```

You might use one of these:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-01-2016 11:29:27',103)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-01-2016 11:29:27',104)
```

Comment: the varchar example i took from w3school https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: @Moudiz Have a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). The first parameter specifies the **target data type**. As you are trying to convert a string-date to a native `DATETIME` you should not use `VARCHAR(24)` in this place...

Answer (score 0):

I believe its inserting as varchar, u can use this script

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(24),'18-01-2016 11:29:27',120)
```

Comment: Did you check this? `Code 120` stands for `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)` which is clearly not the given format...

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Your **target type** is varchar... You are probably relying on an implicit cast, which might work for you (depending on culture settings), but does not work for me... this is plain wrong...

Comment: Exactly, depending on culture settings. If it is dd-mm-yyyy it works either 120, 126. If it is datetime format YYYY-MM-DD, it will  be                 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-01-2016 11:29:27',104) as posted by you

Comment: No, as you are specifying `VARCHAR` as **target type**, you are converting a string to a string... You **do not convert the string to a datetime** If this works for you, it is random...